# Ignoring a specific difference in BC 2.3

Tags: beyondcompare

Using BC 2.3.1

I'd like to exclude the following specific difference from being flagged 'dbeLog' vs. 'dbeOut'

Can I do this, and if so, how?  I've read through other posts, and it's not clear if what I want to do is supported in BC 2.3.  I sort of suspect it can only be done in BC 3.x, as I don't seem to have the menus being referenced by some of the other posts that address this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacements were added in BC 3.  The only way to ignore this in BC2 is to ignore both strings entirely.

Comment: Shoot.  But thanks for saving me a lot of hair loss in the meantime.